# Listener registered multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-6

after registering an event-listener-combo in the `EventServiceProvider.php` there are two listeners shown when running `php artisan event:list`:

```
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Event                             | Listeners                                                   |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| App\Events\VillageCreated         | App\Listeners\VillageInitializer@handle                     |
|                                   | App\Listeners\VillageInitializer                            |
| Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered | Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't know exactly how to deal with the `@handle`-part as this hasn't been registered.

This is the listener:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Listeners;
use App\Events\VillageCreated;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class VillageInitializer
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  VillageCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(VillageCreated $event)
    {
        //
        dd('Hello');
        $initBuildings = \App\Building::where('min_level', '>', 0)->get();
        $event->village->buildings()->attachMany($initBuildings);

    }
}
```

Does this have any consequences for firing events?

Comment: I think you can implement the handler with additional validation to stop propagation when required.

Comment: But I think that there is an error as the event is not handled correctly.

Comment: can you please describe or give more detail about the wrong behavior

Answer (score 3):

The `@handle` listener comes from Laravel's [Event Discovery](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/events#event-discovery), which is disabled by default.

It seems that `event:list` [uses event discovery](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/EventListCommand.php#L51) even when it's disabled but these listeners will not actually fire. Note that **I didn't actually test this**, so I would suggest adding an entry to the log inside the `handle` method (and removing the `dd`) and then manually fire the event and check that there is only one entry in the log.

Alternatively you could enable event discovery and remove the manual registration in your `EventServiceProvider`.

**Update:** Since Laravel scans **all** listeners using reflection it is recommended to cache your listeners in production with `php artisan event:cache`.

There is [a closed bug](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30360) about this issue. I've added a comment to confirm whether or not it was correctly closed.

Comment: Thanks, man. You nailed it.
Do you recommend Event Discovery?

Comment: It depends. I consider event discovery to be Laravel "magic" which might be confusing to developers unfamiliar with it whereas manual registering is more explicit. Also there's performance implications, see my updated answer. Personally, I prefer to be explicit.